# Count current month with "MONTH("Oct"&1)" not working correctly

Tags: google-sheets, count, google-sheets-formula, counting, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to count how many entries I have on a sheet within a month range. 
`=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIFS(MONTH(PHXOctober!D:D),MONTH("Oct"&1),PHXOctober!L:L,"Jeremy"))` - This is the formula I'm using, and it seems to be counting correctly, but it's slightly off when I CTRL F everything from October.

Am I wrong for using `MONTH("Oct"&1)` in my function? I just want a count with everything that has my name on it for the full month of October.

Comment: Actually this works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

your formula is correct and usage of `MONTH("oct"&1)` is also correct

try:

```
=COUNTA(QUERY(PHXOctober!D:L, "select D where L = 'Jeremy' and month(D)+1 = 10"))
```

Comment: Thank you! I've figured out a better way  do this.
=ARRAYFORMULA( COUNTIFS(JIRA!A:A, K10, MONTH(JIRA!B:B), MONTH(NOW()), JIRA!D:D, "*"))